# Which is the correct command to update all anaconda python packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am using python Anaconda. I am confused which is the correct command to update all the Anaconda packages to the latest version. There seems to be 2 commands that can be used;

```
$ conda update --all
```

or

```
$ conda update anaconda
```

After running the latter, anaconda was upgraded to ver4.4. Subsequently, I run the former which asked if I wanted to downgrade some packages. This is what confused me. Which is the correct command to use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `anaconda` package is a "meta"-package, which means that it doesn't contain any packages itself, it merely sets the specific version of a number of packages that Anaconda Inc. (formerly Continuum IO) include with the "Anaconda distribution". Therefore, when you type

```
conda update anaconda
```

you are telling conda to update to the most recent version of the `anaconda` package, and install all the dependencies with their specific versions as specified in the `anaconda` package. This has the advantage that Anaconda Inc. (formerly Continuum IO) have tested the packages together and are making some assurance that there won't be any conflicts.

When you type

```
conda update --all
```

conda uses its internal algorithm to try and resolve the versions of the dependencies. I'm not sure of the details, but this may result in some packages being upgraded, but others being downgraded because some package that you have installed requires a downgraded version of the dependency. Particularly with the number of packages installed by the `anaconda` meta-package, conflicts are sure to happen, and conda is doing its best to resolve all those.

As for which to use, I'd say that if you started with `anaconda`, keep going with `anaconda` to avoid version conflicts (i.e., `conda update anaconda`). However, if you have a fresh environment or you're using Miniconda where you don't have the `anaconda` meta-package installed, then `conda update --all` is probably the better choice. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: From your answer, it seems it is safest not to run `conda update --all` and to keep to `conda update anaconda` only. Unfortunately, I have already run `conda update --all`. Will it cause incompatibilities with anaconda as a result? If yes, how do I reverse the damage? Would running `conda update anaconda` again reverse the damage?

Comment: Probably, `conda install anaconda` would be better, since it should force all the dependencies back to the version specified in the anaconda package. However, you could also just run with it and see what happens!