# Scipy (and seaborn) module import fails after conda update w/ (Py 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pycharm, conda

I recently updated conda and all packages installed. Currently my Python version is 3.6. Simple program as below fails on module import, also to mention that 'seaborn' module too fails.

1. Why does this happen? Even though all packages are updated via conda distribution, dont they check package dependencies on their end and then provide all latest version for users ?
2. If one encounters this problem, whats the firs step to take ? Install and reinstall package or entire conda distribution?

Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def rosen(x):
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0 * (x[1:] - x[:-1] ** 2.0) ** 2.0 + (1 - x[:-1]) ** 2.0)


x0 = np.array([1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2])
res = minimize(rosen, x0, method='nelder-mead',
               options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})

print(res.x)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/abhil/PycharmProjects/CISC-601-ScientificComputing2-Py3/_modules/_scipy_optimize_test.py",
> line 2, in <module>
>     from scipy.optimize import minimize   File "C:\Users\abhil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py",
> line 240, in <module>
>     from .optimize import *   File "C:\Users\abhil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py",
> line 37, in <module>
>     from .linesearch import (line_search_wolfe1, line_search_wolfe2,   File
> "C:\Users\abhil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\linesearch.py",
> line 18, in <module>
>     from scipy.optimize import minpack2 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

What's the difference between

> conda update conda

and

> conda update anaconda

Comment: To answer your last question, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45821755/2449192